# How to deploy geoserver behind nginx with a custom port?

Tags: docker, nginx, geoserver

I want to deploy geoserver (and some spring-boot services) behind nginx on the same server, both are in saperate docker containers. I have to config custom port other than 80 and 443, which are not available for same reasons. I choose 10443 for https scheme.

Those spring-boot services work well, while geoserver not. Once the geoserver url requested, browser is redircted to another url without port number. For example, visiting https://example.com:10443/geoserver will be redirected to https://example.com:10443/geoserver/index.html, then https://example.com/geoserver/web/?0 --- the port 10443 is omitted somehow.

How to config geoserver and nginx correctly?

my nginx config:

```
location /geoserver {
  proxy_pass http://geoserver:8080/geoserver;
  proxy_set_header    Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify SUCCESS;
  proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
  proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject $ssl_client_s_dn;
  proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer $ssl_client_i_dn;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/cert:/etc/nginx/cert
      - ./nginx/www:/www
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  geoserver:
    container_name: geoserver
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.21.1
    environment:
      DB_BACKEND: POSTGRES
      HOST: postgis
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_DB: pgis
      POSTGRES_USER: postgis
      POSTGRES_PASS: ********
      GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER: admin
      GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ********
      GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR: /opt/geoserver/data
      GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR: /opt/geoserver/cache
      FOOTPRINTS_DATA_DIR: /opt/geoserver/footprints
      HTTP_SCHEME: https
    volumes:
      - ./geoserver/data:/opt/geoserver/data
      - ./geoserver/cache:/opt/geoserver/cache
      - ./geoserver/footprints:/opt/geoserver/footprints
      - ./geoserver/fonts:/usr/share/fonts/custom
```

Any suggestion helps. Thanks in advance.

---

Update: added `HTTP_PROXY_PORT: 10443` in environment section of geoserver fixes this problem.

Comment: did you set the proxy URL in the global settings page of GeoServer?

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for your tips, I found an environment variable named HTTP_PROXY_PORT, which fixes the problem.